# zipping lists with an optional list to construct a list of object in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a case class like this:

```
case class Metric(name: String, value: Double, timeStamp: Int)
```

I receive individual components to build metrics in separate lists and zip them to create a list of Metric objects.

```
def buildMetric(names: Seq[String], values: Seq[Double], ts: Seq[Int]): Seq[Metric] = {
    (names, values, ts).zipped.toList map {
         case (name, value, time) => Metric(name, value, time)
    }
}
```

Now I need to add an optional parameter to both buildMetric function and Metric class.

```
case class Metric(name: String, value: Double, timeStamp: Int, type: Option[Type])
```

&

```
def buildMetric(names: Seq[String], values: Seq[Double], ts: Seq[Int], types: Option[Seq[Type]]): Seq[Metric]
```

The idea is that we some times receive a sequence of the type which if present matches the length of names and values lists. I am not sure how to modify the body of buildMetric function to create the Metric objects with type information idiomatically. I can think of a couple of approaches.

1. Do an if-else on `types.isDefined` and then zip the types with `types.get` with another list in one condition and leave as above in the other. This makes me write the same code twice.
2. The other option is to simply use a while loop and create a Metric object with `types.map(_(i))` passed a last parameter.

So far I am using the second option, but I wonder if there is a more functional way of handling this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option can't be done because `zipped` only works with tuples of 3 or fewer elements.
The second version might look like this:

```
def buildMetric(names: Seq[String], values: Seq[Double], ts: Seq[Int], types: Option[Seq[Type]]): Seq[Metric] =
  for {
    (name, i) <- names.zipWithIndex
    value <- values.lift(i)
    time <- ts.lift(i)
    optType = types.flatMap(_.lift(i))
  } yield {
    Metric(name, value, time, optType)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

One more option from my point of view, if you would like to keep this `zipped` approach - convert `types` from `Option[Seq[Type]]` to `Seq[Option[Type]]` with same length as `names` filled with `None` values in case if `types` is `None` as well:

```scala
val optionTypes: Seq[Option[Type]] = types.fold(Seq.fill(names.length)(None: Option[Type]))(_.map(Some(_)))
// Sorry, Did not find `zipped` for Tuple4 case
names.zip(values).zip(ts).zip(optionTypes).toList.map {
  case (((name, value), time), optionType) => Metric(name, value, time, optionType)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. Its a good approach but I was surprised to see that the Seq.fill operation seem very cpu intensive. When testing this out, cpu utilization in my cluster went up from 4-5 % to 50-70% !

Answer (score 3):

You could just use pattern matching on `types`:

```
def buildMetric(names: Seq[String], values: Seq[Double], ts: Seq[Int], types: Option[Seq[Type]]): Seq[Metric] = {

  types match {
    case Some(types) => names.zip(values).zip(ts).zip(types).map {
        case (((name, value), ts,), t) => Metric(name, value, ts, Some(t))
    }
    case None => (names, values, ts).zipped.map(Metric(_, _, _, None))
  }
}
```